# learning EXTJ as a newbie

Tags: javascript, extjs

hello I started to learn ext
I have installed extj and I can browse examples from local host successfully

from examples

```
    Ext.require('Ext.chart.*');
    Ext.require(['Ext.Window', 'Ext.layout.container.Fit', 'Ext.fx.target.Sprite']);

    Ext.onReady(function () {
 //lob lob lob
```

it seems to me EXT is a class which has many objects where I can find ext itself?
I tried hard to find it but I couldn't find it through these huge files
for example what Ext.chart.* means?
what the second line means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ext.require('Ext.chart.*');` means all Ext javasript files in chart folder will be included in the script. Chart.* says all files under chart hierarchy.

```
 - chart 
      +Axies
      +series
      +theme
      -callout
      -Chart
      -Hightlight
      -Label
      -Legend
      -LegendItem
      -Mask
      -Navigation
      -Tip
```

You can browse the chart hierarchy [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.chart.Chart).

Comment: Ext javasript files in chart folder from where the code can know it?EXT is where that originally defined?

Comment: There are few primary files like bootstrap.js. This file loads ext-all.js from sencha.com. Ext comes from there. They have defined paths of all files and they load automatically. You can check in the firebug. As you keep on learning, you will understand more clearly.

Comment: I found it it is in ext-debug.js it is a class which is defined in there hmm the contents are not simple for me

Comment: great ! Use ExtJs documentation always.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking a broader question of where to start learning the ExtJS as a framework.
And I think a clear answer here is their guides: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide

Start with the Getting Started guide and the Class System guide which has naming conventions as well. Depending of what you will be doing with the framework you may want to read the other guides like Components and MVC(for most apps that have more than one panel:) ).

Then as you focus your attention on specific capability (like charts, grids or forms) switch over to the examples and look into source code behind them. You'll find many interesting ideas there.

Finally as you start to develop your app and extend out of the box components keep the API docs open at all times :) They help tremendously and also let you see what happens when you change this or that config right there in the live preview. This has been very helpful to me.